# How to remove the spaces for a particular column in UNIX

Tags: unix

How to remove the blank spaces from a particular column in UNIX

Actual data:
0001|10462740807|014904740  |115822708|
It should be: the third column spaces should be removed
0001|10462740807|014904740|115822708|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat input
0001|10462740807|014904740 |115822708|
$ awk '{gsub(" *","",$3)}1' FS=\| OFS=\| input
0001|10462740807|014904740|115822708|
```

`gsub` in awk globally replaces all occurences of the regex `' *'` with an empty string in the specified string. In this case, we specify the input separator as `|` and do the replacement in the third column.  If you are only wanting to replace trailing space, you can use `" *$"`.  If you want all whitespace (eg, tabs), you can use:

```
awk '{gsub("[[:space:]]*","",$3)}1' FS=\| OFS=\| input
```